# Spring boot security x-auth-token not found in header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, redis, glassfish

I have a spring boot application having REST services secured with spring security. Redis is used for storing sessions. I have deployed the application in Glassfish 4.1.2. When trying to login using basic auth, `x-auth-token` is not returned in response header. What could be the issue ?

Below are my configuration classes:

**ApplicationSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource source;

@Autowired
private HttpLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;  

@Bean
public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
    return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/crr/**").access("hasRole('CRR')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationDetailsSource(source).authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.csrf().disable();
  }   
}
```

**CORSCustomFilter**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) 
public class CORSCustomFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
        ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization");
    chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

public void destroy() {
 }
}
```

**Note:** When I deploy the application in Tomcat,`x-auth-token` is successfully generated in response header.

Comment: Why do you believe `x-auth-token` should be present in a Response?

Comment: @dit I'm using `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`. So there should be a `x-auth-token` generated in response header.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve it from response headers, Add x-auth-token to Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Access-Control-Expose-Headers

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-auth-token");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "x-auth-token");
```

This worked for me.